# get loops in a linked list C#

Tags: c#, data-structures, singly-linked-list

I have a program to make a linked list in c# like this:

```
class Point
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Point> NextPoints { get; set; }

    public Point()
    {
        NextPoints = new List<Point>();
    }
}
```

This is the point object with name and next points.

I fill a list of points with data,

```
List<Point> Points;
```

And I have a line defined here:

```
class DashedLine
{
    public Point X { get; set; }
    public Point Y { get; set; }

}
```

And I need a recursive function to get the loop made by a given **DashedLine**

So that I pass the **DashedLine** object, and the function returns a list of points that make the loop.

Please help me doing this function.

Comment: you should either use a list for all objects (in your case a sorted one preferably), or a linked list ( storing the next object within the object itself ). Mixing them up sounds like a bad idea

Comment: I see only some classes. Where is function which causes propblem?

Comment: If a point has a list of points it's no longer a list, it's either a tree or a graph.

Comment: Indeed, it should either have a reference to the next Point object, or just belong in a list of Points where the next Point is naturally index+1

Comment: Aside from your data structures, how do you expect to get a loop from a line? Can you give an expected output given a example DashedLine?

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing your data structures, maybe something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DashedLine line = new DashedLine();
        line.Points.Add(new Point { X = 1, Y = 1 });
        line.Points.Add(new Point { X = 2, Y = 2 });
        line.Points.Add(new Point { X = 3, Y = 3 });
        line.Points.Add(new Point { X = 4, Y = 4 });

        foreach (Point p in line.Points)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Point {0}, {1}", p.X, p.Y);
        }
    }
}

class Point
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}

class DashedLine
{
    public List<Point> Points { get; set; }

    public DashedLine()
    {
        Points = new List<Point>();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Point 1, 1
Point 2, 2
Point 3, 3
Point 4, 4
```